# silverstripe model admin content is not displayed to content authors

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

there is a model admin section in the cms. for the content authors the model admin section shows up in the sidebar (i´ve set Access to 'ModelAdmin' section in the Permissions for the Group.) But for some reason no DataObjects are displayed. Logged in as admin I can see them all.

EDIT: this applies to GridFields in general:
related data objects are not visible in gridfield for content authors.
adding the canView function to the dataobject will help.

Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SilverStripe 2.4?

This could be a permission issue. I would try adding the following functions to your managed models (The DataObject classes) if they are missing.

```
public function canEdit() {
    return true;
}

public function canDelete() {
    return true;
}

public function canCreate(){
    return true;
}

public function canPublish(){
    return true;
}

public function canView(){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: hey ryan! it´s ss 3.0.2. i added these can Functions but nothing changes..., regards, Florian

Comment: I just added canView as well, then it´s perfect. regards, Florian

Comment: is this secure? it isn't just setting that anyone can edit that model admin is it?